# How to obtain the zip filename being downloaded in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zip, nsurlconnection

Currently using SSZipArchive method to download the zip file and unzip at Documents directory folder. I am downloading the zip file name from URL and currently unaware of the file name because it changes each time there are any updates. How can I retrieve the file name when I receive my data ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   directoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ZipFiles.zip", directoryPath];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/test/test.cfc?id=123"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:url];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

[fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:urlData attributes:nil];
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:directoryPath];

 NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


 ///***Answer to my own question for future needs****//
  NSString *fileName = [response suggestedFilename];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSURLResponse` has a method `- (NSString *)suggestedFilename` which will attempt to get the file name in this order.

1. A filename specified using the content disposition header.
2. The last path component of the URL.
3. The host of the URL.

The [content disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header would be the best solution so make sure that the server sets it.

Comment: Joe: Thanks it did work. Just wanted to ask you a simple question on the same topic: How will you send the filename as POST over HTTPRequest? Like how can I use that as string and send it as POST ?

Comment: I am not actually sure since I have not tried it buy try sending the content-disposition header back and then checking for that on the server.